# On editing the newsletter from the customer dashboard, it goes to a blank page

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, blocks, newsletter

When i click on the edit link in the newsletter section of my account page. it goes to a blank page, also when i check the ManageController in the newsletter section,

```
if ($block = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('customer_newsletter')) {
        $block->setRefererUrl($this->_getRefererUrl());

    }
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQelD.png]

above section is not working.

Comment: Enable the error from index.php and paste the exact error message with stacktrace.

Comment: There is no error , the block customer_newsletter is not getting in the manage controller. the screenshot of the page is given above.

Comment: Probably error is there, that's why page doesn't process further and stop at the error. You need to enable display_errors in php.ini settings first.